# C compiler's FP based on non-IEEE 754: is such C compiler C standard compliant?

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754, standards-compliance

If a C compiler's FP is based on non-IEEE 754, then is such C compiler C standard compliant?

Comment: You should not ask questions in this form: If a compiler does X, then is it compliant? The actual question you want to ask is “If a compiler does X, is that particular behavior non-compliant?” This is because a compiler can do X, which is, by itself, compliant, but the compiler might also do Y, which is non-compliant. E.g., a compiler might fully conform with the C standard in all its floating-point behaves but fail anytime the source code contains a routine named `foobar`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: that is taking pedantry to its limit! The question is clear and well written, in my opinion.

Comment: @TonyK: This poster has written dozens of pedantic questions about the C standard and IEEE 754. That is what they are seeking.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Haha! Yes, you're right. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) is concerned, the representation used for floating point numbers is **unspecified**.

Section 6.2.6 covers Representation of Types.  In particular, 6.2.6.1p1 states:

> The representations of all types are unspecified except as stated in this subclause.

And nowhere in section 6.2.6 are floating point types mentioned.  So an implementation may use any representation it chooses, and it is not required to document that decision.

Comment: That means the bit-level representations of floating-point numbers are not specified. However, characteristics of floating-point types are specified in 5.2.4.2.2. A floating-point type must represent numbers in effect as a sign and a fixed number of digits in a fixed base multiplied by the base to an exponent with fixed limits, optionally plus infinities and NaNs.

Answer (score 3):

If the implementation says it conforms to IEEE 754/IEC 60559 (`__STDC_IEC_559__` is defined), it must do so.

But the C standard does not require that. [C11 footnote 356](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#note356):

> 356. Implementations that do not define `__STDC_IEC_559__` are not required to conform to these specifications.

C does not not require for example binary floating point - the minimal requirements include for example that any floating point type must have range of at least 1e-37 to 1e37